# How to read Numeric value in excel file in java using selenium web driver

Tags: java, excel, selenium, vba

I have try to read numeric value form excel.
I have value 119710179 this is numeric but when it read  that time it display cellvalue--1.19710179E8

Help me!

```
This is my code:-

FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File ("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Deepa\\Desktop\\AMC test cases1.xls")); 
 HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
 HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Clinic Basic info");
 WebElement creat_new_website =driver.findElement(By.className("createnew"));
 creat_new_website.click();

 driver.findElement(By.id("primaryno_m")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(sheet.getRow(13).getCell(4).getNumericCellValue()));
```

Comment: `sheet.getRow(13).getCell(4).getNumericCellValue()` will return a `double`. Then [String.valueOf(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-double-) leads to [Double.toString(double d)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-). So what is unclear with that description and the hint to `NumberFormat`?